# How to create an embed code for video for websites?

Tags: video, youtube, embed

I'm am just trying to find out if there is any software available for turning home video that I've created into embed codes for websites?

I know i can use youtube but that only allows me a 10 minute video and I want to go bigger.

It would be great if there was some sort of software that just transfers the video into an embed code.

If anyone knows of anything like this I would be very thankfully if you shared...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vimeo](http://vimeo.com) is similar to youtube but allows you to go for longer than 10 mins (and allows embedding).